# The flow of time and relativity: the Now hypothesis of Richard Muller

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, time

Richard Muller has, in a recent [Physics Today](http://physicstoday.scitation.org/do/10.1063/PT.5.3047/full/) interview, argued that time is incorrectly incorporated into special and general relativity, suggesting that while you can choose any coordinate system and stand still at that position, this is something that you can't do with time.

From the link above:

> The basic postulate of the now theory is that creation of space is accompanied by the creation of new time. In the now theory, the moment we call “now” is the time that was just created to match the new space created from the expansion of the universe. In the LIGO event, about a millisecond of new time should have been created locally, just barely below the observable threshold for that event. When LIGO sees a stronger event―it’s seen some weaker ones―then the theory should be falsifiable.

How would relativity (indeed quantum field theory) needed to be modified to take this into account?

Comment: This appears to tread close to a request for peer review, which [is off-topic here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7516/50583). Can you try to formulate this more as an objective physics question and less as "how seriously do you take Rickard Muller"?

Comment: I looked for any publication of Muller's ideas in a scientific paper, and I didn't find any. There is just his recent pop-sci philosophy book. He is basically a planetary scientist, and the vita on his web page does not list anything related to general relativity as one of his current research interests, nor does his list of publications appear to include anything on GR. He actually doesn't seem to be currently active in research. His most recent paper listed on his vita is from 2005. The pop-sci book was reviwed by Bojowald: http://physicstoday.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/PT.3.3466 .

Comment: I think that, absent any references to an actual *theory*, this question isn't answerable at all.  even in that case it might fall under the no-peer-review clause.  But does he actually have any papers on this?

Comment: if he had had anything serious to publish a new theory of time he would have worked on it and published it in a serious journal. Having said that I am pretty disappointed at the pass that Physics Today is giving him - I don't think that teaching Physics for President qualifies anybody to say they know physics or do physics research. Still, I've 'met him' at the physics Forums online (meaning I've seen his posts), and he's reasonably knowledgeable to that forum. I think the question does not belong on this site. It's not about physics because there is no physics there. Well, IMHO.

Comment: Actually it was Quora, not Physics Forums. Had forgotten the name. The link below is one of his self-promoting postings. https://www.quora.com/How-did-Richard-Muller-decide-how-to-price-his-book-Now-—-The-Physics-of-Time