# How does according to modern physics collision between two massive black holes create new space or new spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, astrophysics, gravitational-waves

[Now (hypothesis) -- And the Physics of Time](https://www.npr.org/sections/13.7/2016/09/27/495608371/now-and-the-physics-of-time)

In this page the author talks about (find in page) (in the context of LIGO Observatories-->) "In their most powerful event, reported just this past February, the combination of two massive black holes should, according to general relativity theory, have resulted in a massive amount of new space in the vicinity of the final star"
Please explain my question. I don't get this!!!

Comment: Here's an arXiv preprint on the subject: ["Now, and the Flow of Time"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.07975) by Richard A. Muller (author of the npr.org article) and Shaun Maguire. The preprint is from 2016, but I can't find evidence that it was ever published. It's not mainstream physics, and it's most likely wrong.

Comment: Related: [The flow of time and relativity: the Now hypothesis of Richard Muller](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/346145/the-flow-of-time-and-relativity-the-now-hypothesis-of-richard-muller)

Comment: Yes, it is most likely wrong. That's my opinion too @benrg